# Avoiding repeating state names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Let's say i have a *rootreducer* like below.

```
const rootR = combineReducers({
  topics,
  ...
});
```

the *topics* reducer

```
function topics(state = { topics=[], error: null}, action){
  switch (action.type){
    case types.FETCH_TOPICS_SUCCESSFULLY:
      const { topics } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        topics,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And when i fire the related action i get my state with repeatable properties `state.topics.topics` instead of `state.topics`

Is there any way to avoid this repeating (`topics.topics`)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `const { topics } = action;` what does the topics object look like here?

Comment: @finalfreq this is array of objects like > `{userId, theme, body}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the initialState of your `topics` reducer, the state object accessible to `topics` reducer has this structure:

```
{
    topics: [],
    error: null
}
```

So when you `combineReducers` like this:

```
const rootR = combineReducers({
  topics,
  anotherReducer,
  someOtherReducer.
  // ...
});
```

resulting **global app state** is going to look like this:

```
{
    topics: {
        topics: [],
        error: null
    },
    anotherReducer: {
        // ...
    },
    someOtherReducer: {
        // ...
    },

    // ...        
}
```

So if you want to access `topics` array from global state, you need to do `state.topics.topics`.

You have two things under `state.topics`, an array of `topics` and `error`.
Hence let's rename second `topics` key to `items` to avoid confusion.
(it is unavoidable to have a second key to store the array because you also want `error`)

thus we have:

```
state.topics = {
    items: [],
    error: null,
}
```

Instead of `state.topics.topics`, now we access `state.topics.items`

To achieve this, initialstate passed to `topics` reducer has to be:

```
function topics(state = { items = [], error: null }, action){
    //...
}
```

Now inside the reducer `FETCH_TOPICS_SUCCESSFULLY`, we want to append an array `action.topics` to `items`, like this (without mutating our current state):

```
case types.FETCH_TOPICS_SUCCESSFULLY:
    const { topics } = action;
    return {
        ...state,
        items: [
            ...state.items,
            ...topics
        ],
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You're double-nesting things.  The `topics` reducer will only see the "topics" slice of state.  So, instead of returning `{...state, topics}`, just do `return topics`.

**update**

Your edit to the question changes the situation considerably.

Originally, you had:

```
function topics(state = {}, action){
```

Now, you have:

```
function topics(state = { topics=[], error: null}, action){
```

I'll admit I'm a bit confused at this point as to what your desired state structure actually should be.

Looking at your original definition, it seemed like you were misunderstanding how `combineReducers` works, and redundantly trying to return a new object that contained a field/slice named "topics".  Now, it looks like the root-level "topics" slice itself has a field named "topics" as well.

Are `topics` and `error` supposed to be at the *root* of your state tree?  Or, are they both really supposed to be part of the top-level "topics" slice?  If that's really what you want, then you've defined the state tree as needing to be `topics.topics`.

Also, to answer @free-soul: no, in the original example, `return topics` would *not* mutate state, because it's just returning whatever was in the action.  Even if the `action.topic` field was literally the same array that used to be in the state, the result would just be a no-op.

Comment: I have to return an object. Now i dont handle the error, but i the future i will. Does it make sense?

Comment: @markerikson, `return topics` is going to mutate the state. Also in the original question he has `state.topics` an object whereas `action.topics` is an array.

Comment: @markerikson, I think I will have to disagree. The state accessible to `topics` reducer is `{ topics: [ item1, item2, ...], error: null }`. Consider `action.topics = [item3, item4]`. So if you do `const { topics } = action;` and then `return topics` from the reducer, the resulting state will be `[item3, item4]`. The state becomes an array, and you lose the previous items in `topics` and also `error`. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @free-soul : My original response was based on the original sample code, where the `state` argument, labeled `topics`, _was_ an array.  Either way, `return topics` is not a "mutation" as such, since a "mutation" is a direct modification of an existing object or array reference.  `topics.push()` would be an example of a "mutation".

Answer (score 1):

@markerikson is right, the `state` variable passed in the function is actually `topics` once `FETCH_TOPICS_SUCCESSFULLY` is called, so it's better to do `return topics` there. 
But given your condition,  instead of return `{...state, topics}` or `return topics`, you can also do return `Object.assign({}, state, topics)`. This will create a new object with all properties from previous state and topics merged together.